# 'The head office' or just 'head office'?

Tags: articles

I've got a question. Tried to google it, but nothing came up.
So, there is a sentence:

> "How often do you visit head office?"

Why don't we use "the" before "head office"? Sometimes I see examples with "the head office" but sometimes without.

Is there any rule?

Comment: It's an example of the null (rather than the zero) article. The term 'head office' has almost become a title, as in 'He is king'. So much so that the alternative 'the head office' would be used rarely outside such contexts as 'She visited the head office of Smethers yesterday'.

Comment: Yes. People in an organisation abbreviate. I had a call from head office, Peter is dating a girl from Accounts.

Comment: In this particular case, there may be a variance between British English and American English. " visit the head office" sounds better to me (American), but I've definitely heard just " visit head office" from British friends.

Comment: As a BE speaker, I don't see anything remarkable about "head office."

Comment: As a US military veteran, I think "head office" (sans article) has a humorous connotation.

Comment: @RobJarvis - Yeah, it's where all the a-holes reside!

Comment: Just don't ask the head nurse is she is in charge of bathrooms...

Comment: @robjarvis exactly what is the etymology of the head?

Comment: It's common to use business departments or divisions without an article: "Call human resources", "Take this to goods received", etc. Intuitively you could often capitalise these and treat them as a proper name. (Although you'd still say "the mail room", "the cafeteria", I guess.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But you can't drop the article in *_He visited king._

Comment: Different, but maybe related - *I went to the city*, but *I went to town*.

Comment: I also believe this is a transatlantic difference. In AmE we do say headquarters but I have not heard any AmE speakers saying "head office".  Although other Britishisms are catching on recently ... bespoke...spill the tea...done and dusted....pride of place.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, but not: take this to head office.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you think of it as a thing or the name of a thing. In this case the speaker probably thinks of it as the name of the said part of the organisation and sees it with a capital H and O (no article required for names).

Answer (score 0):

*There is only one head office in any organization*. Ergo, it is "the head office", which is one of the rules for using "the".

There are other reasons in other contexts.

> 2. for a unique or fixed referent: the Prime Minister, the Lord, the Times, the Suez Canal;

This use of "the" is used in most varieties of English.

Another example:
For a company, one says: *the chairman of the board* because there is only one in a company. However, we can use the plural: Chairmen of the board at large companies are often rich, white men.

[use of the for a unique thing](https://www.thoughtco.com/definite-article-grammar-1690423)

AND

> The definite article the is used to refer to a specific noun (i.e.,
> one that is unique or known).
>
> Examples: Definite article in a sentence
> The moon looks beautiful
> tonight.
> Can I borrow the book on the table?

[parts of speech_determiner_a UK site](https://www.scribbr.co.uk/the-parts-of-speech/determiner/)

Example from an actual text:

> Head office means *the head office* for the time being of the Company;
> 2. *The head office* of the Company is situated in England [...]    revocation shall have been received by the Company at the head office

[Franklin Templeton_UK](https://www.franklintempleton.co.uk/download/en-gb/articles-of-incorporation/cc3962e3-cf1c-47b0-a3af-6d7f4ff2fec5/FTF-articles-en-gb.pdf)

With the exception, for example, of defining *head office* as is done in the example above, *count nouns* need either a determiner or a plural. We say: I like dogs, and we don't say: I like dog. [sounds like you eat them! as in "I like chicken".] "I like head office" is not grammatical in English.

Bear in mind that there are cases where particular organizations or trades may use what is considered ungrammatical in standard writing.

Comment: There's only one President of the United States. But idiomatic is 'He was elected President.' This is the null article rather than the zero article, which according to [Master](https://escholarship.org/content/qt2kb4p9r0/qt2kb4p9r0.pdf?t=lb7ioa) is more definite even than 'the'. In [Ggl ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=head+office%2Cthe+head+office&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the results for "head office" outperform those for "the head office" (you have to 'subtract' the graphs for a true comparison ... but "head office" is over twice the ht).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nope: He was elected president. No capital p. You cannot use ngrams for this as you cannot show context and you cannot therefore set out a usage argument. He was banned from head office? Don't think so.

Comment: [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visited+head+office%2Cfrom+head+office%2Cat+head+office%2Cvisited+the+head+office%2Cfrom+the+head+office%2Cat+the+head+office&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) are hard to explain away. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/head-office) gives  actual examples: 'A directive comes from head office indicating that there is no time to allow people to take part in local community activities.' / 'The budget needs to be referred to head office for final approval.'(+ others)

Comment: And as for the correctness of using the capital P in 'elected President': 'On November 8, 2016, Mr. Trump was elected President in the largest Electoral College landslide for a Republican in 28 years. ' ([US] [National Archives](https://trumpwhitehouse.archives.gov/people/donald-j-trump/))

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is not the same because he is NAMED in the sentence. In yours, he wasn't. Could be any old president.

Comment: You didn't use to: to head office versus to the head office: to **the** head office **wins**: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+head+office%2C+to+head+office&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: 'He was elected President in November 1932, to the first of ....' [[TheWhiteHouse.gov](https://www.whitehouse.gov/about-the-white-house/presidents/franklin-d-roosevelt/)] (but of course who 'he' refers to has already been mentioned in a previous sentence). Sometimes the lower case is appropriate, sometimes either. // Some of the 'to the head office' are false positives such as 'to the head office network' and 'to the head office of Execom' where the definite article is forced. It remains the case that 'visit head office' is totally idiomatic, at least in the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *I didn't say it wasn't idiomatic, did I? I explained why the is used when it is used for a single instance of something. Is that ok with you or not?

Comment: 'There is only one head office in any organization. Ergo, it is "the head office" ' conveys the impression that using say 'We were contacted by Head Office' is incorrect. It's not. Though I'd certainly use the definite rather than the null article in say 'From the Head Office of GCB Bank Ghana' as is found on the internet (I might drop the capitals H and O).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The same question was asked on ELL and the person flunked an Indian teacher exam due to it.  The examiners wanted a "the". I can't be expected to explain the whole universe. But you tried to downplay my ngram search which contradicts yours.